Installing Landscape gives "Job for landscape-appserver.service failed because the control process exited with error code."
Using the quick setup here, it gets near the end and begins to give errors. I am trying to install this on an Oracle Cloud ARM 2 core 8 GB RAM instance. I am using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, however, I have also tried 24.04 LTS. Currently, I am using 22.04 LTS with the kernel 6.5.0-1021-oracle. These are the errors it gives:
See "systemctl status landscape-appserver.service" and "journalctl -xeu landscape-appserver.service" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript landscape-appserver, action "start" failed.
x landscape-appserver.service - LSB: Enable Landscape frontend UI
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/landscape-appserver; generated)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2024-05-02 03:22:55 UTC; 5ms ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Process: 12481 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/landscape-appserver start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 4.694s

landscape-appserver[12502]: Failed to load application: File "/opt/canonical/landscape/canonical/landscape/ui/accesscontext/configure.zcml", line 23.4-28.10
landscape-appserver.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Failed to start LSB: Enable Landscape frontend UI.

When I try to connect from my client servers, I get the error
Request a new registration for this computer now? [y/N]: y

Traceback (most recent call last):
Failure: landscape.lib.amp.MethodCallError: timeout
Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

When I go to the domain, it just says "landscape is unavailable Service will resume shortly."
